# TableSorter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, tablesorter

The tableSorter plugin is not working.I have downloaded the plugin included in file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="~/Assets/js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="sortTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="danger" >
                                    <th>TOKENS</th>
                                    <th>REVISIONNOTES</th>
                                    <th>REVISION</th>
                                    <th>TARGETPROFICENCY</th>
                                    <th>QUESTIONSAVAIL</th>
                                    <th>QUESTIONSTOASK</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {       
   $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
});
```

[image: I can see the TableSorter plugin is loaded during Run]

When i debug the code, it says 'tablesorter' is not an function, basically the plugin is loaded i believe. I dont know what wrong i have did, could anyone please help. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your html code is wrong. Also I have implemented an example for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/xrda9p5t/

html:

```
<table id="sortTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr class="danger" >
        <th>TOKENS</th>
        <th>REVISIONNOTES</th>
        <th>REVISION</th>
        <th>TARGETPROFICENCY</th>
        <th>QUESTIONSAVAIL</th>
        <th>QUESTIONSTOASK</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>test </td>
        <td>test </td>
        <td>test </td>
        <td>test </td>
        <td>test </td>
        <td>test </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
   $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
 });
```

make sure you have added all the files properly. It's a good practice add the scripts files at the end of the html.

Hope it's helps!

Comment: make sure you use a proper jquery version. @SunVigna

Comment: gon250. Thanks for your reply. I dont see any difference in HTML i copied ur code and ran but still the same result, no sorting is happening. As i said the tableSorter plugin is not added. i have added an image of the browser console

Comment: can you share your code by github or something, I'll solve your problem. @SunVigna

Comment: i can't share the code, basically i am not allowed to. but the table is very simple  as shown in my first message. table inside an <div> with header and body. i have question the table is inside an iframe, so is it make any difference ?

Comment: haha of course, then I know your problem. @SunVigna let me test if we can apply the tablesorter to a table inside a iframa

Comment: I have never tried that, but I'm pretty sure after the iframe appear you can get the iframe (``var $iframes = $('iframe');``) and look for the table and apply the javascript code. Also Close this question and create a new one because I have answer your question. @SunVigna